Override package-defined tmLanguage.json in project
Let's say I have an extension installed in VS Code which defines a tmLanguage.json file for some programming language X. I want to override this definition for a particular project.
My two questions are: How can I add my custom file to my project an override the package defined one? Is there a way of doing this without having to create a custom extension?
